# Everyone must do one's duty

Tags: grammar, word-choice, american-english, pronouns, british-english

Please let me know which is the correct answer?

1. Everyone must do **one's** duty.

**(a) his** (b) everyone's
(c) their   (d) No improvement

I believe option **a** is the correct answer.

Comment: These days it is the singular gender-neutral **(c) their**.

Answer (score 1):

The most common usage is (c) but if the audience is all male or it's an archaic context, you will likely see (a).